# Which word should be use when talking about gathering for a language corner meetup

Tags: word-choice

We have a monthly language corner gathering(not sure if use gathering is appropriate). And so when talking about gathering together for that event, can I use something like :

**We're going to have our next language corner "meeting" or "gathering" on next Friday?**

Another word that I know is "meetup", but not sure if it's a real word. Or it's coming from the site: `Meetup`

Comment: "noun: meetup - an informal meeting or gathering" It seems that it suits perfectly and answers almost all your question https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/meetup

Comment: Questions in Stack Exchange sites require a minimum research effort. You should check at least available resources online before posting.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @RubioRic. You're right, I didn't do a thorough search on the word "Meetup". I only did it on Merriam webster's learner dictionary but didn't find out anything. I think I'll keep the question open since I'm still not sure if the word "meeting" or "gathering" can be used in this context and the reasons behind them. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Perhaps the best place to look for a word you’re not sure about is [OneLook](https://www.onelook.com/?w=meetup&ls=a), which will search in over a dozen online dictionaries for a word. When it shows only four hits (like _meetup_ does), that’s a pretty good sign that a word is informal and perhaps non-standard. (in contrast, OneLook finds the word _[gathering](https://www.onelook.com/?w=gathering&ls=a)_ in more than 20 online dictionaries.)

Comment: Looks like a handy tool! Thank you @J.R. I've been learning English for over a decade, but finding a right word to use is still a big challenge to me.

Comment: @konekoya - My favorite online dictionary is [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/gathering), which actually pulls from four or five dictionaries with every lookup, and finds example usages from contemporary news stories. You should check it out and maybe even bookmark it :-)

Comment: I'll definitely give it a try and bookmark it. I really love this community and your help. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both *meeting* and *gathering* would work in your announcement.

The one difference I can tell you that may be hard to figure out from the dictionaries is that *meeting* has a bit more of a formal feel to it, while *gathering* feels less formal. (I’m not talking about the formality of *language* here; I’m talking about the formality of the *event*.)

Put another way, I go to ***meetings*** when I’m at work, I go to ***gatherings*** on the weekends with my friends.

So if your “language corner” is a formal occasion with an agenda, then *meeting* might be the better word to use. However, if it’s more of an informal gathering with cookies and punch served, than *meeting* may not be quite the right word for it. (It wouldn’t be wrong, but I sense that perhaps you want to use something “warmer” and more inviting.)

A nice alternative might be [***get-together***](https://www.wordnik.com/words/get-together), which one dictionary defines as: *a casual social gathering*. It’s not as formal as *meeting*, but it’s more recognizable than *meet-up*. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/get-together) defines it as:

> an informal meeting or party, usually arranged for a particular purpose

while [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get-together) says:

> meeting; especially : an informal social gathering

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation @J.R. This has clear up my doubt for these words.